# What's the equivalent of this.props.formik on a function component?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a class component on which I can get formik values as the following:

```
    const { values } = this.props.formik;
```

How can I do the same in a function component since I don't have access to `this.props.formik`?

Comment: In a functional component, props are passed into the function as a parameter, conventionally they are just called `props`, but the name may vary from case to case. What does your entire component look like?